# How do you query custom HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I can't figure out how to query custom HTML elements. I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that hides certain course cards on Brightspace, an online learning web app, but can't query the custom HTML elements on the page.

I've tried using `document.querySelectorAll("d2l-enrollment-card")` to access the custom element, but that just returns an empty `NodeList`.

This is the custom HTML element:

```
<d2l-enrollment-card href="https://49859a61-b438-442b-b8f8-ff36ea34d011.enrollments.api.brightspace.com/enrolled-user/6oac9Iqccnpjv3IJOzSAJctvUDASjnH-wPfoWmMTjmU/enrollment" dir="ltr">
</d2l-enrollment-card>
```

Comment: try to give these components a class and select them by this particular class

Comment: How can I add a class to the component code if I can't find a way to select it?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) how to add classes to an element

Comment: I might be missing something, but this is not my code so can't just add a class in the code.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why `querySelectorAll()` wouldn't return them. Are you sure you're running it after the elements are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try accessing the custom elements with their tag name?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('d2l-enrollment-card')
```